# slideToggle a fieldset from a <select> option?

Tags: jquery

I would like to "slideToggle" a fieldset based on a single option being selected in a  element using jQuery. The source is generated by a framework, and at this time the following output is all I have to work with. I would like to know how to do this by value.

I would like the fieldset that is ID'd "toggle-me" to slideToggle the display from none to block when the option "Option_2" is selected. If it is unselected, I would like the display to return to none. This is the only option that will toggle the fieldset. Below is the source. Thank you.

```
<select name="options" id="id_options">
  <option value="Option_1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="Option_2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<fieldset id="toggle-me" style="display:none">
  <div>
   .....
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by binding an event handler function to the change event of the select element

```
$("#id_options").bind('change', function () {
   if($(this).val() === 'Option_2') {
      $("#toggle-me").show();
   } else {
      $("#toggle-me").hide();
   }
});
```